# Loop through JSON and extract array / description, help required

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, loops

```
[
{
    "Description": "Accommodation",
    "ChartData": [
        {
            "label": "Acceptable",
            "data": 24
        },
        {
            "label": "Excellent",
            "data": 30
        },
        {
            "label": "Good",
            "data": 96
        },
        {
            "label": "Poor",
            "data": 2
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "Description": "Food and Beverage",
    "ChartData": [
        {
            "label": "Acceptable",
            "data": 44
        },
        {
            "label": "Excellent",
            "data": 24
        },
        {
            "label": "Good",
            "data": 94
        },
        {
            "label": "Poor",
            "data": 13
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Description": "Meeting Space",
    "ChartData": [
        {
            "label": "Acceptable",
            "data": 30
        },
        {
            "label": "Below Expectations",
            "data": 2
        },
        {
            "label": "Exceeds Expectations",
            "data": 3
        },
        {
            "label": "Excellent",
            "data": 54
        },
        {
            "label": "Good",
            "data": 111
        },
        {
            "label": "Meets Expectations",
            "data": 7
        },
        {
            "label": "Poor",
            "data": 6
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "Description": "Service",
    "ChartData": [
        {
            "label": "Acceptable",
            "data": 25
        },
        {
            "label": "Exceeds Expectations",
            "data": 3
        },
        {
            "label": "Excellent",
            "data": 46
        },
        {
            "label": "Good",
            "data": 111
        },
        {
            "label": "Meets Expectations",
            "data": 8
        },
        {
            "label": "Poor",
            "data": 11
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Description": "Standard of Decor",
    "ChartData": [
        {
            "label": "Acceptable",
            "data": 38
        },
        {
            "label": "Excellent",
            "data": 34
        },
        {
            "label": "Good",
            "data": 126
        },
        {
            "label": "Poor",
            "data": 5
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Using the above JSON, how do I loop through each and assign two variables containing the description, and the array for ChartData in jquery/javascript i.e.

```
foreach() {
var Description = data[].Description;
var ArrayOfChartData = data[].ChartData;
}
```

I've tried using an .each loop but can't return the correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript arrays have a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```
data.forEach(function (v) {
    var Description = v.Description;
    var ArrayOfChartData = v.ChartData;
    // now use that...
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u7RuZ/

---

Unfortunately, IE < 9 does not support this. If you have to support IE8, you can use jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
    var Description = v.Description;
    var ArrayOfChartData = v.ChartData;
    // now use that...
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u7RuZ/1/

Comment: Tried that already.

  $.each(data, function (i, v) {
        var Description = v.Description;
        var ArrayOfChartData = v.ChartData;
        alert(Description);
    });

returns "undefined" - and pressing ok keeps returning undefined.

I'm using MVC so am converting my model to JSON like the following:

var data = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Summary))';

Could that be the problem?

Comment: @user1981131 - `forEach` or `$.each`?

Comment: @user1981131 - Of course that's the problem. Remove the quotes: `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Summary));`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [......] has no method 'forEach'... getting this error. What type does the data variable need to be in? Its returning @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Summary)) at the moment

Comment: omg!! damn quotes! Thank you so much. Took me ages figuring this out when it was just quotes causing the problem :(